# React context not showing latest update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-cloudwatch, react-context

I'm trying to use context to use some data somewhere else in my app, the data in question in an instance of aws cloudwatch Rum.

The context code logs out the object instance but this object fails to be passed into to the component, I think its created after the component is rendered. Even with useEffect, which is supposed to update after something changes, doesn't re-render or update after the object is logged. Any ideas?

Context code:

```
import { AwsRum } from "aws-rum-web";
import React, { useRef, useEffect, createContext, useContext } from "react";

const AnalyticsContext = createContext(null);
export const useAnalytics = () => useContext(AnalyticsContext);

const AnalyticsProvider = ({ children }) => {
    console.log("running aws cloudwatch");
    const rumRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!rumRef.current) {
            rumRef.current = createRum();
            console.log(rumRef.current);
        }
    }, []);

    const createRum = () => {
        try {
            const config = {
                (config strings...)
            return new AwsRum(APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_VERSION, APPLICATION_REGION, config);
        } catch (error) {
            // Ignore errors thrown during CloudWatch RUM web client initialization

            return null;
        }
    };

    return (
        <AnalyticsContext.Provider value={{ rum: rumRef.current, test: "blah" }}>{children}</AnalyticsContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default AnalyticsProvider;
```

Component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useAnalytics } from "../context/analyticsContext";

const Header = () => {
    const { rum, test } = useAnalytics();
    console.log(rum, test);

    const recordClickEvent = (nameOfElement) => {
        console.log("running click event aws");

        rum.recordEvent(nameOfElement, {
            user_interaction: {
                interaction: "click",
            },
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(rum);
    }, [rum]);
```

App:

```
<AnalyticsProvider>
<App/>
</AnalyticsProvider>
```

I can log out "blah" from the test key. I can log out the object instance from the Context code, however the object instance is alway null in the component.

Comment: Try to read this article about using Rum in React applications: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/using-amazon-cloudwatch-rum-with-a-react-web-application-in-five-steps/

Comment: Its a good article but it talks about placing all the code in App.js, which is real life just doesn't work like that

Comment: why not just `const rumRef = useRef(createRum());`? I think you don't need an effect at all here

Comment: Yes, that works too and is a cleaner solution, I will update my answer@thedude

Answer (score 0):

I had to save the AWS object instance as state of course! in order for the useEffect to work it has to update when a state has updated.

```
const AnalyticsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [rumRef, setRumRef] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!rumRef) {
      setRumRef(createRum());
    }
  }, [rumRef]);

  return (
    <AnalyticsContext.Provider value={{ rum: rumRef }}>
      {children}
    </AnalyticsContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Now I can I get the object instance in my component:

```
const Header = () => {
    const { rum } = useAnalytics();
    console.log(rum);
}
```

UPDATE: no need to use useEffect, this can all be done with useRef like this:

```
const createRum = () => {
... creates the aws instance object
}

const rumRef = useRef(createRum());

return <AnalyticsContext.Provider value={{ rum: rumRef.current }}>{children}</AnalyticsContext.Provider>;
};
```

Don't forget the .current